# Can you Control the Order of Hooks "Firing" in Drupal?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules

If two modules implement the same hook in Drupal, does the system have a way to define which order the hook functions are called, or is it just luck of the draw/alphabetical ordering?  Or something else? Or does my question show I misunderstand hooks in some fundamental way that makes me look dumb?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The order is determined based on the weight setting for the module in the system table. If two modules have the same weight, the order is alphabetical.

Comment: Basically correct (+1), with the missing detail that it will be alphabetical, if two modules have the same weight.

Comment: Thanks!  Follow up question: As a third party developer, what's "the correct" way to slot my module's weight in this table?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at module weight in database,
or use http://drupal.org/project/moduleweight