# Module code for hook_form_alter problem

Tags: drupal, module

I have a select dropdown list from a taxonomy applied to multiple node types on my site.
The problem is not all the terms are relevant to all the node types.

**What I am attempting to accomplish is a small module which will detect and current node being editted and selectively remove irrelevant terms from the the select list.**

However, when I do a print_r or dpr on $form within the hook_form_alter, the terms of the taxonomy are not exposed. So, I can't do and unset or other relevant action to remove the necessary term(s).

I hope that's clear enough.

I need help, please give me some assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to fire your hook after taxonomy module which is as simple as changing weight in system table to be higher than taxonomy

Comment: I'm sorry but you have completely lost me just then.                   Would you mind elaborating this point so I can better under you?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994579/can-you-control-the-order-of-hooks-firing-in-drupal

Comment: Every module including yours has it's own weight (think order default 0) this order is preserved in hook calling stack , therefore u need to have your module be weighted more than taxonomy . u can Achieve this  by updating  'weight' in system table  in db